# Geometrical meaning of partial derivative of implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

My question is about the Implicit Function Theorem. I am considering the case $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. The theorem gives conditions under which, given a function $f(x,y)$, it is possible to write locally $y$ as a function of $x$. That is, near a point $x_0$, we can write $y= y(x)$. If we have a point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfying $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \ne 0$, then $y = y(x)$ near $x=a$, with $y(x)$ a function with the same regularity as $f$. The equation $f(x,y)=0$ defines a curve in the plane. My question is: what does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=0$ means? If you could include a picture I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A level curve of $f$ is a set of points $(x,y)$ satisfying $f(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$; here $c=0$, but it could be any other value and the implicit function theorem would still hold. At each point $(x_0,y_0)$ of a level curve, the gradient vector of $f$, $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0),  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right)$, is perpendicular to the level curve (meaning, it is perpendicular to the tangent line to the level curve). If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=0$, we have a horizontal gradient vector in the plane; that means the tangent to the level curve $f(x,y)=c$ (which we'd hope is the graph of $y$ as a function of $x$) is vertical at $(x_0,y_0)$. When this happens we cannot guarantee $y$ is locally a $C^1$ implicit function of $x$. Two examples of what can go wrong: 1) $f(x,y)=x-y^2$ at $(0,0)$ ($y$ is not even a function of $x$, though $x=y^2$), 2) $f(x,y)=x-y^3$ at $(0,0)$ ($y$ is a function of $x$ but not differentiable due to a vertical slope in its graph). Draw out these two examples and you will understand it.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it!

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the graph of $f$ as a a mountain range then the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$ means that, along the curve $f(x,y) =0$, the mountain range has a nonzero slope in $y$ direction. This means that if you move in the $y$ direction, you will leave the $0$ niveau. If that derivative is $=0$, you are on a (potentially infesitimally small) plateau. If you move in the $y$- direction in this case it may happen that you remain on the $0$ niveau (so the solution to $f=0$ may fail to be unique for that value of $y$).

Drawing a picture of this is quite easy, but I think you will get the most out of it if you do it on your own.

Comment: Thinking about the 3D graph of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, I understantd that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ means that the slope of the tangent line to the curve given by the intersection of the graph of $f$ and the plane $x = x_0$, and it measures the rate of change of $f$ along the $y$ direction. My problem is going from 3D to 2D, from considering the full graph of $f$ to the level curve $f(x,y) = 0$. In 2D there is no tangent curve to the graph of $f$, so how can I get the picture?

Comment: Let's imagine the 3D picture corresponding to the idea of $frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0)$, with the grapf of $f$, the plane and the tangent curve I mentioned. Seeing it from above, we get the level curves of $f$. But the tangent curve will always look like a vertical line. So how can I distinguish between different slopes?

Comment: If you project down to 2 dimensions you will loose information. In the situation of the implicit function theorem (with the $y$ derivative being _non_ zero) you will just know that the level curve $f=0$ will be transversal (not parallel) to the $ x = x_0$ line. That's actually the key observation for the validity of the implicit function theorem and a nice basis for a proof in the simple 3D case.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the meaning of the partia derivatives regarding the level curves? Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but I cannot see it

Comment: It's not really transparent to me what you are missing, the geometry is actually quite simple. Maybe you really follow your own advice and try to draw a (3 dimensional) picture. Or you use an online tool to draw the graph of a simple function.